# How to stop a sub-container div from expanding

Tags: css, user-interface, containers, frontend

I have this container that I want to stop from expanding when populated with data. I want to know how can I achieve this in css. I have here fourcontainers. Main container(black),sub-container(orange), sub-container1(blue), sub-container2(green). Main container has fill-height of screen. I set the Sub-container1 with 85% of the height of main-container and sub-container2 with 15%. I want to stop sub-container1 from expanding more from its height if I put many contents. Can someone help me how I can achieve this in css?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add css below to main-container class:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: I tried this with my main container and to my sub-container1 but sub-container1 still expands the main-container's height.

Comment: If i try to populate the sub-container1 with many data, the main-container's height expands its height.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox together with `overflow: auto;`:

```css
#main {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 180px;
}

#container-1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 0 1 85%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#container-2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  flex: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"><div id="container-1">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a aliquet ex, non aliquet tellus. Nullam dolor neque, accumsan id blandit non, iaculis quis nisi. In eget sapien sodales, bibendum turpis at, imperdiet eros. Nunc viverra tristique quam, vitae hendrerit urna porta quis. Aenean augue justo, consectetur eget placerat id, porttitor id mauris. Sed consequat pellentesque ultrices. Morbi at dui auctor, consequat tellus in, sagittis tortor. Sed elementum, sapien ac euismod imperdiet, ex ex ornare augue, pellentesque semper ligula est at risus. Ut in ligula felis. Nullam ipsum ex, mollis non congue id, luctus ut augue. Morbi condimentum laoreet elit vel viverra. Aenean vel erat lacinia, aliquam est nec, sollicitudin ipsum. Vestibulum porttitor sollicitudin odio, ut laoreet enim pretium venenatis. Nunc condimentum tortor sed enim hendrerit, varius egestas orci commodo. Morbi sit amet maximus magna. Donec ut finibus elit. Cras convallis ipsum ut facilisis consectetur. Aenean tristique, quam a vulputate vestibulum, tortor metus dictum sem, sit amet varius ligula nibh vitae tortor. Quisque dapibus arcu nisi, in ornare quam tristique eget. Pellentesque facilisis nisi vel odio semper gravida. Phasellus lectus sapien, viverra eu nibh id, varius egestas metus. Nullam viverra, dui vel pulvinar sollicitudin, mauris massa tincidunt lacus, ut ornare. </div><div id="container-2">2</div></div>
```

Comment: This one works but I only want the scroll to happen within the container-1 not the whole container.

Comment: Do I still have to add max-height for main container even if I already added fill-height to its class?

Comment: `fill-height`...?

Comment: Yes, please see the new image. The container is within a container.

Comment: The overflow auto happens in the sub-container1 but my main-container still expands.